# Css for imagebutton

Tags: asp.net, css

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution to setting css border to a asp image button.

Css Script on page in the header

```
            .HoverBorder {border:5px solid #eee;}
            .HoverBorder:hover {border:5px solid #5CB3FF;}
```

Image Button on Page in Body

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CssClass="HoverBorder" SkinId="ButtonSkin" 
         ImageUrl="~/images/gnome_view_refresh.png" ToolTip="Refresh" Width="30px" Height="30px"  />
```

It is supposed to set a border then on hover change borders color. Any ideas why its not working as intended. All help very much appreciated.

Comment: It works for me just fine. Tested in IE9 and Chrome 18 - The border OnHover becomes light-blue.

Comment: Oh, hmm im using IE 8 and chrome 18 also, I wonder why its not working for me?

Comment: Can we please see the HTML as it's rendered in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try rollover like so

```
 .HoverBorder:rollover {border:5px solid #5CB3FF;}
```

You can also see if something in the css for SkinId "ButtonSkin"  is overriding your border.